# loadNib fails with a Thread 1 - Breakpoint 1.1

Tags: ios, view, nib

Here is part of my code :

```
LocalPosts *cell = (LocalPosts *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LocalPosts" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
```

I have a .xib named LocalPosts - my code fails just there with Thread 1 - Breakpoint 1.1

I have all exceptions ON and enabled Zombies but I do not see anything printed on the console - just the (lldb).

I am running it on ios 8.0 on a device  and I am using latest xcode.

I don't even know where to look at - can you help me on that?

Thanks

Comment: Breakpoint? Are you sure you haven't added a manual breakpoint? By the way, note that you don't have to load nibs manually since iOS 5, you can register the nib with the table and it will create your cells automatically.

Comment: @Sulthan I haven't yes - I was using that code on release 1.0 of my app - and now I am reviewing it and suddendly start failing - can you point me an example of what you are saying?

Comment: @Sulthan manual breakpoint is only for All exceptions

Comment: Check the documentation for `[UITableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]`.

Comment: Could there be a problem with the `owner`? Not sure why you want the cell to be loaded with some owner because you can't really use an owner there. Also make sure you are running the app in Debug mode so that you can actually see what's happening. If you let the code continue running after getting an exception, usually you will get the exception message printed out.